# Writing a plugin file in ClojureScript for use in CKEditor

Tags: clojurescript, ckeditor4.x, reagent, re-frame, shadow-cljs

I currently have a project that is using ClojureScript, shadow-cljs, re-frame, and CKEditor.

I am trying to figure out how to write a custom plugin for CKEditor usoing CLJS instead of JS.

CKEditor uses the following to load external custom plugins

```
// Loads a plugin from '/myplugins/sample/my_plugin.js'.
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/', 'my_plugin.js' );
```

Is there a way to write `my_plugin.js` in CLJS in my current project?

Comment: I think your going to have to be more specific. Have you tried? What issue did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is: *I have a CLJS project that uses shadow-cljs and happens to use CKEditor as a library. I also want to create a plugin for CKEditor within the same project.*

If that's the case, I think what you need is just create a new build for the plugin code in the `:builds` section of your `shadow-cljs.edn` file and configure it properly (eg. source files, etc.). See the [Build Configuration](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_build_configuration) section of the shadow-cljs User's Guide for details.

Once you build your plugin, it will put the output JS file in some location. Probably you need to copy this plugin JS file to a location in the "parent" project before building the main project.

Comment: I do believe your answer is going in the right direction, but my unfamiliarity with CLJS and shadow-cljs is getting in my way. I am going to have to come back to this a little while latter and hopefully I can get it working. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't know much about your project and how you want to extend CKEditor, but depending on the features of plugin, you may want to consider writing it in plain JavaScript. ClojureScript is great but for a trivial extension it may be overkill.

Comment: I hear you, it is probably easier to write in plain JavaScript, but since I am already in a CLJS environment I thought it would make sense to also use ClojureScript to develop the plugin as well. It seems that thought might be a bit naive though. Seems to me like that would be a big hole for CLJS if you have to fire-up another environment to produce JS code for a project already being developed with CLJS; I am sure as with most things, there is probably a good reason for this, but it sure crushed my dreams of "one language to rule them all" :)   Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: There might be some hope: maybe you can declare your CKEditor plugin as a module that depends on the code the main app, so that you don't have two copies of the CLJS runtime but just one. See the [Code Splitting](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#CodeSplitting) section of the CLJS User Guide.

Comment: That looked promising at first unfortunately, this app is an SPA so separate pages is not an option.